# Rails email action text attachment link_to not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, actionmailer, actiontext

After implementing `@mentions` to `Article` models `has_rich_text`, everything works fine but when I try to send these articles as an email, the mentions fail to render right. I see `sgid` and `content`, via the inspector but the html just renders a "☒" for the `@mentions`.

The rails mailer preview shows everything fine, i.e. the mention renders correctly. However, in production it fails to render correctly.

EDIT:
After getting some sleep and revisitng the docs I realized that `link_to` wont work per the docs:

> As the :host usually is consistent across the application you can
> configure it globally in config/application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

> Because of this behavior, you cannot use any of the *_path helpers
> inside of an email. Instead, you will need to use the associated *_url
> helper. For example instead of using

```
<%= link_to 'welcome', welcome_path %>
```

> You will need to use:

```
<%= link_to 'welcome', welcome_url %>
```

> By using the full URL, your links will now work in your emails.

Need to implement and find out, will update. Reading the docs it seems that Passing in the `Active Record model` does not work:

> More concise yet, when name is an Active Record model that defines a
> to_s method returning a default value or a model instance attribute

```
link_to @profile
# => <a href="http://www.example.com/profiles/1">Eileen</a>
```

therefore need to provide the `url` also.

Any ideas why this would be/how to fix?

Production:

```
<action-text-attachment sgid="eyJfcmFpbHMiOnspJaXhuYVdRNkx5OWhjRE12VFhWelkyeGxMekUyUDJWNGNkZWQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJhdHRhY2hhYmxlIn19--31217260f33fc8fce3243" content-type="application/octet-stream" content="<a data-turbo-frame=&quot;_top&quot; data-class=&quot;description&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;/gadgets/muscles/triceps-brachii&quot;>
        Triceps Brachii
</a>">☒</action-text-attachment>
```

This just creates an "☒" as you can see.

Dev:

```
<action-text-attachment sgid="eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaTFuYVdRNkx5OWhjR1Y0TFcxdmNuUDJsdUJqb0dSVlE9IiwiZXhwIjhdHRhY2hhYmxlIn19--391d3670aff9" content-type="application/octet-stream" content="    <a data-turbo-frame=&quot;_top&quot; data-class=&quot;description&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;/gadgets/muscles/abductor-hallucis&quot;>
        Abductor Hallucis
</a>">    <a href="/gadgets/muscles/abductor-hallucis">
        Abductor Hallucis
</a></action-text-attachment>
```

Which creates a `link_to` for Abductor Hallucis.

For the site to render the content inside `ActionText`/`Trix`, I have the following:

`_exercise_mention.html.erb:`

```
<%= link_to exercise, data: { turbo_frame: "_top", class: "description" }, target: :_blank do %>
    <%= exercise.name.humanize.titleize %>
<% end %>
```

`_exercise_mention.jbuilder:`

```
json.extract! exercise, :id, :name

json.sgid exercise.attachable_sgid
json.content render(partial: "exercises/exercise_mention", locals: { exercise: exercise }, formats: [:html])
```

`Exercise model:`

```
class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
    include ActionText::Attachable
......
    #show mentions Article
    def to_trix_content_attachment_partial_path
        "exercises/exercise_mention"
    end
    
    #edit mentions Article
    def to_attachable_partial_path
        "exercises/exercise_mention"
    end
end
```